# What is exactly modes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, developer-mode, default

I have overridden Luma theme and created a custom theme for our store. We have made the website live also. I need to know what are modes as i searched there are 3 modes default, Developer and Production. I checked with below command

php bin/magento deploy:mode:show

I am getting result as Default like below

Current application mode: default.

Do i need to set it to Production if so please explain What is the difference in each. Does it cause any problem if it is Default mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set your application as Production mode.

To set application as production mode, run below command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

There are Three mode available in Magento-2.

**Default** : By default mode set as default.

**Developer** : for development purpose

**Production** : for live application

Details Explain as per devdocs [About Magento modes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html)

**default**

Enables you to deploy the Magento application on a single server without changing any settings. However, default mode is not optimized for production.

To deploy the Magento application on more than one server or to optimize it for production, change to one of the other modes.

- Symlinks to static view files are published to the pub/static
  directory
- Exceptions are not displayed to the user; instead, exceptions are
  written to log files.
- Hides custom X-Magento-* HTTP request and response headers

**developer**

Intended for development only, this mode:

- Symlinks to static view files are published to the pub/static
  directory
- Provides verbose logging
- Enables automatic code compilation
- Enables enhanced debugging
- Shows custom X-Magento-* HTTP request and response headers
- Results in the slowest performance (because of the preceding)
- Magento Commerce (Cloud) supports production mode only.

**production**

Intended for deployment on a production system, this mode:

- Does not show exceptions to the user (exceptions are written to logs
  only).
- Serves static view files from cache only.
- Prevents automatic code file compilation. New or updated files are
  not written to the file system.
- Does not allow you to enable or disable cache types in Magento Admin.
  More information about enabling and disabling the cache.

Comment: Once we set production mode, If we need to make any changes on some files again do we need to set it into Default? Or directly we can make changes on files?

Comment: Directly you can deploy your changes to production mode.

Comment: If you change in .php .xml .phtml then it need to just clean cache. if you change in .js .css and html static files it need to deploy static content.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will set it to Production.

Answer (score 0):

You can read magento document for it very well understanding [Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html).

**Default  Mode:** 
          Exceptions are not displayed to the user; instead, exceptions are written to log files.

**Developer Mode :** Results in the slowest performance (because of the preceding)

**Production Mode :**

1.Does not show exceptions to the user (exceptions are written to logs only).

2.Serves static view files from cache only.

Answer (score 0):

By Theory as per Magento docs -

```
**Default** 

Enables you to deploy the Magento application on a single server without changing any settings. However, default mode is not optimized for production.

To deploy the Magento application on more than one server or to optimize it for production, change to one of the other modes.

Symlinks to static view files are published to the pub/static directory
Exceptions are not displayed to the user; instead, exceptions are written to log files.
Hides custom X-Magento-* HTTP request and response headers

**Developer**


Intended for development only, this mode:

Symlinks to static view files are published to the pub/static directory
Provides verbose logging
Enables automatic code compilation
Enables enhanced debugging
Shows custom X-Magento-* HTTP request and response headers
Results in the slowest performance (because of the preceding)

**Production**


Intended for deployment on a production system, this mode:

Does not show exceptions to the user (exceptions are written to logs only).
Serves static view files from cache only.
Prevents automatic code file compilation. New or updated files are not written to the file system.
Does not allow you to enable or disable cache types in Magento Admin.
```

By Practical use( Actually just adding some points that will be noticed while working :) ) -

The Default mode is the mode which is initiated when the Magento2 is installed. It is not ideal for development. You can not come back to default mode, once you have switched to any other mode.

The developer mode, is used for development purposes. The frontend is slow, but the logs are activated and you will be able to see the errors. The commands usage changed to some extent. Like php bin/magento s:s:d becomes php bin/magento s:s:d -f

The production mode as said is the mode needed for live environment. The errors are not displayed on frontend in this mode.

While switching from developer to production mode or vice versa, s:s:d and s:d:c needs to be ran.

The commands to check mode show-

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode: show
```

or

```
php bin/magento d:m:sh
```

The command for set deploy mode -

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

or

```
php bin/magento d:m:set developer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between three different **Modes in Magento**.

**1- Default Mode**

Basically it is a mixture of both *Developer and Production Mode.*

As per **DEVDOCS Magento **, in Default Mode-

- Static view file caching is enabled
- Exceptions are not displayed to the user; instead, exceptions are
  written to log files.
- Hides custom X-Magento-* HTTP request and response headers

**2- Developer Mode**

In this mode all the error messages are displayed directly on the web page, you will immediately aware of the issue. This is the slowest mode due to the lack of a Caching Function.

**3- Production Mode**

- It does not show exceptions to the user.
- Serves static view files from cache only.
- Prevents automatic code file compilation. New or updated files are
  not written to the file system.

**Change Mode in Magento 2**

You can change the Modes by running the following command in CLI.

```
bin / magento deploy:mode:set {mode}
```